# HAProxy - http_req_rate

Tags: haproxy

I have read the HAProxy [blog post](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/application-layer-ddos-attack-protection-with-haproxy/) about DDoS protection.

At the section about [Limiting Request Rates](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/application-layer-ddos-attack-protection-with-haproxy/#limiting-request-rates) they are describing an example to set the limit to 100 to get a detecting of 10 hits per second.

Is there a reason for this selection? Wouldn't a limit of 10 with 1s period do the same or is there anything to consider:

```
backend per_ip_rates
    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 10m store http_req_rate(1s)
```

with

```
http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 10 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Natural browsing (i.e. by a person) can produce bursts of connections.  For example, if you load a web page, plus the images on that page, plus CSS, plus some JavaScript, you could pretty quickly get to 10 connections in a second.

It is also reasonable that a person loads a home page/landing page and then within a few seconds clicks a second page.

However, it is unlikely that a natural person would generate traffic at a sustained pace over a longer time period - they will not click page after page after page *ad infinitum*.

This *sustained* traffic is what (typically) differentiates automated traffic from occasional bursts associated with natural browsing.

To put it another way, the longer the period you average over, the more confident you can be that the traffic exceeding a "connections per second" threshold is the result of automation.

However, choosing a longer period is not without disadvantages - a longer period means higher memory requirements for the table and a slower response time.  The choice is a balance of these things.

Once you choose the period to average over, the number of connections needs to be set conservatively so that you do not catch (i.e. block) natural browsing.

Comment: I know that 10 connections per second is pretty small. I know that’s only an example not a practical value but I don't understand der difference between the different periods: 10s & 100 or 1s & 10 or 20s & 200 or 30s & 300 ==> all of them results in 10 connections per second. Why is it better to prefer the 10s & 100 over 1s & 10. You write to identify that the threshold is abnormal. How would I know that 10 connections per second are abnormal with a period of 10s against 1s - what’s the difference?

Comment: As said, the larger the statistical sample, the greater your confidence in a prediction.  This is a basic statistical principle.

Comment: It looks like I'm not getting it... Assuming I have a blank page (no JS / CSS / Picture, nothing) and I set `http_req_rate(10s)` with `sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 8` ... A normal user (refreshing his browser) will be able to hit 9 times within 10s, but a normal user will never be able to hit 9 times in 1s - just a bot would be able to do 9 requests per second. Second example: `http_req_rate(10s)` and `sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 100000` ... no normal user wouldn't be able to hit 100000 in 1s or 10s, but a bot would be able. So what is the difference if a bot will hit 100000 in 10s or 10000 in 1s.

Comment: I think my confusion has started with this (see blog post): **So, to cap requests at 10 per second, set the limit to 100** ... I misunderstood that or translated it to a different meaning. I thought that the requests will be blocked after 10 requests within 1s. I simply tried it and it will need of course the fully 100 hits to get the DENY. My fault... If I want to have a deny after 10 requests within 1s, then I have to set period = 1s and limit = 10. In the blog post they have meant the average, which I have misunderstood. That was the point where my confusion has started.